# Count occurrences of repeating elements in a vector<vector<Object>>

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `vector<vector<Rect>>`. `Rect` is a openCV rectangle object. I want to fill up a empty `vector<pair<Rect,int>>` with all the rectangles that are repeating (1 or more occurrences) in the vector and the number of found occurrences.

My implementation below is not giving me the expected result. Here is what I tried:

```
vector<vector<Rect>> vec;
//...fill up vector vec...
vector<pair<Rect,int>> constantsVec;
bool found=false;

for(int j=0;j<vec.size()-1;j++){
    vector<Rect> temp1=vec[j];
    vector<Rect> temp2=vec[j+1];
    for(int x=0;x<temp1.size();x++){
        for(int y=0;y<temp2.size();y++){
            if(temp1[x]==temp2[y]){
                for(int k=0;k<constantsVec.size();k++){
                    if(constantsVec[k].first==temp1[x]){
                        found=true;
                        constantsVec[k]=make_pair(temp1[x],++constantsVec[k].second);
                    }
                }
                if(!found){
                    constantsVec.push_back(make_pair(temp1[x],0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In an example with a rectangle that is repeating three times I end up with the correct rectangle in the `constantsVec` but with 1 as the number of found occurrences instead of 3.

I should add that one element (`vector<Rect>`) of the `vec` vector itself has no repeating rectangles but between the elements of the `vec` vector there can be repeating rectangles. Those are the ones I am trying to find and count.

Comment: It is a good idea when to reach two indented for loops to start using a function. Makes the code more readable

Comment: If you are testing my answer, check it again as I edited and simplified it. Regards.

Comment: You should use `const vector<Rect>& temp1=vec[j];` to avoid copying the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient and possibly the simplest way to do that in O(n · log n) is to use a map.

First create a `Rect` comparator to allow indexation by `Rect` (put it somewhere accessible):

```
// Needed for O(n · log n) complexity
struct RectComparator {
    bool operator () (const Rect & a,const Rect & b) {
        if (a.x != b.x) return a.x < b.x;
        if (a.y != b.y) return a.y < b.y;
        if (a.width != b.width) return a.width < b.width;
        return a.height < b.height;
    }
};
```

To count how many `Rect r` you have in `vec` here's the code:

```
vector<vector<Rect> > vec;
//...fill up vector vec...

map<Rect, int, RectComparator> counts;
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < vec[i].size(); j++) {
        counts[vec[i][j]]++;
    }
}
```

I didn't check if `vec[i][j]` exists on `counts` as if it does not, it's initialized to zero by default.

At the end, `counts[r]` will have the amount of `Rect r` in `vec`.

The complexity is `O(n · log n)` with `n` the amount of `Rect` in `vec` vs. `O(n^2)` (yours).

---

To iterate over the `counts` map here's the code (adapted to build the `constantsVec` if you need it, with `Rect`s that appear more than once):

```
vector<pair<Rect, int> > constantsVec;
map<Rect, int>::iterator iter;
for (iter = counts.begin(); iter != counts.end(); ++iter) {
    // iter->first is the Rect
    // iter->second is the count of the Rect iter->first in vec
    if (iter->second > 1)
        constantsVec.push_back(make_pair(iter->first, iter->second));
}
```

Take into account that it makes sense to build and use `constantsVec` only if you will use it many times and at the same time the difference between rectangles that appear once and those that appear more than once is significantly big. In other case, using the `counts` map should be as good as using the `constantsVec`.

Comment: I am not able to compile this. `counts[vec[i][j]]++;` seems to be the problem. I'm failing to see how this could work. Where does it compare two rectangles to see if they are the same?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, you have to `#include <map>` first (I've added it to the answer). They are compared internally with the == operator.

Comment: Map is included. Where is the == operator in your code?

Comment: It is not necessary. If you have a `Rect r` (any), the first time `count[r]++;` is executed `count[r]` will be 1. The second one 2, and so on. As I told you, the `==` operator is executed **internally** to index by the key (`vec[i][j]` in this case).

Comment: I've recently added to the answer how to iterate the resultant map.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I am still not able to compile this. Map is included and I did a clean build.

Comment: What compilation errors are you getting? I swear this should be the most optimal and simple answer (I've competed in important programming contests)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72474/discussion-between-axelbrz-and-testus).

Comment: `mingw491_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h:367: error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const cv::Rect_<int>' and 'const cv::Rect_<int>')`

Comment: I updated the answer. A Rect comparator was missing, now it's there ;)

Comment: The problem was because I was mistaken. The operator used internally is < instead of ==. That comparation structure fixes that.

Comment: depending on how you're using the collection, it's possible you want `unordered_map` or `unordered_set`.  Also note that if order is important (not sorted order) you'll need a different container.  `unordered_map` has different requirements than `map` for its held types.